# iOS8 NSLayoutConstraint causing issues and UIButton not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Updated to XCode 6.2 with iOS 8.2, btw be prepared to suffer some serious horrible Constraint issues, and now my app UI is trashed. I didn't set constraints and and each view has about 100 UI elements on it so they are scattered everywhere. Anyway, so I am on one view and have spent about 20 hours trying to get the constraints right because of the detail of how my view is laid out. So I have a button that I have made a specific constraint for using the Storyboard editor. I have set the

```
top Space to: 36
Trailing Space to: 18
Width Equals: 60
Height Equals: 44
```

Now when I tap the UIButton nothing happens. Its doesn't even change color so it isn't recognizing my tap. I have re-established the constraints 20 times and it will never allow me to tap it anymore.

Ok apparently I need to go into very explicit detail here. There is nothing on top of it. I have thrown a breakpoint and viewed it in the expand view stuff in iOS6 it is the front most item in the entire view. I have set the constraints setting it 15 pixels from the right edge. and 26 pixels from the top edge. It's there and nothing is blocking it.

Comment: No I complained and then gave exact NSLayoutConstraints.

Comment: Is the button's superview the main view, or some subview? This problem is almost always caused by the button being outside the bounds of its superview.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Not sure how, but about the 10th time of setting and resetting constraints it just worked.